# How can I have these radio buttons sit next to each other inline

Tags: html, css

I am using a 'reveal-if-active' class to reveal content underneath the buttons. I have tried a few things using CSS and have tried to move around the html tags but it causes issues.

I updated my question with the specific code I am trying to do. The previous link was a generic code snippet of a similar concept.
FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/3qeryw75/1/

```html
<h4>Which do you like more?</h4>
<div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-dogs" required>
    <label for="choice-animals-dogs">I like dogs more</label>

    <div class="reveal-if-active">
      <label for="which-dog">Good call. What's the name of your favorite dog?</label>
      <input type="text" id="which-dog" name="which-dog" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#choice-animals-dogs">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please use semantic tags

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap them in a `<div>` and make the `<div>`'s use `display: inline-block`...

```
 <div>
     <div style="display:inline-block;">
         <input type="radio" name="choice-animals" id="choice-animals-dogs" required>
         <label for="choice-animals-dogs">I like dogs more</label>
     </div>

     <div class="reveal-if-active" style="display:inline-block;">
         <label for="which-dog">Good call. What's the name of your favorite dog?</label>
         <input type="text" id="which-dog" name="which-dog" class="require-if-active" data-require-pair="#choice-animals-dogs">
      </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if thats what you want, but try this:

```
form > div > div {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This is the result you should get:
[image]

Comment: keep in mind, this way will apply the styles to all divs inside a div housed in your form

Comment: I am not getting those results

Comment: That might be becuase you didn't add it at the end of your css.

Comment: Oh, I was using your codepen. I think the guy above me solved the problem, but here is a fiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/n4px6od9/1/